# File path problems in windows environment

Tags: java, filepath

I have the following line of code:

```
"%s/ramp_adapter/user_%d/ramp_file_receipt/%d".format(new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath().replace("/.",""), endpointId, fileId)
```

If I print this line in window I get wrong file path:

```
E:\git\project\codeAdapters\rampAdapter\./ramp_adapter/user_1001/ramp_file_receipt/3
```

In unix, the file path is coming correct.

I know that I need to make it compatible with windows and so I tried using [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) but this didn't resolved the problem.

The path should be correct in all the environments.

Comment: What is `E:` in unix?

Comment: This looks wrong.  Windows back slashes and unix uses forward slashes.

Comment: @SkinnyJ - I didn't looked on unix systems but there it is running fine. The location I assumed and have kept in my question which seems wrong after looking your comment and so I deleted it.

Comment: Have you tried using `java.nio.file.Paths.get(String first, String... more)` to build the path rather than string replacements? You will get the proper drive root and path separator according to the runtime.

Comment: your endpoint is wrong `./ramp_adapter/user_1001`... are you persisting `./` part?

Comment: @JordiCastilla - he's trying to replace it with an empty string via `.replace("/.","")`, but it isn't working because with the code he currently has, the String value ends up as `"\."`, which doesn't meet the replace method parameters.

Comment: @JoshDM if you store correct paths and use correct separators you don't have to replace or maipulate your strings between operating systems, that's why I ask.... I think workaround is unnecessary here

Comment: @JordiCastilla - I agree; I'm just explaining what I can only infer he was doing with his existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
"%s/ramp_adapter/user_%d/ramp_file_receipt/%d"
```

with

```
"%s" + File.separatorChar + "ramp_adapter" + File.separatorChar + "user_%d" + File.separatorChar + "ramp_file_receipt" + File.separatorChar + "%d"
```

Replace

```
getAbsolutePath().replace("/.","")
```

with

```
getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separator + ".", "")
```

Comment: I can just imagine the perfection to tackle different environments by such separators. Quoting for `File.separatorChar` - "The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\\'." voila!!

Comment: While my answer is functionally correct, I suggest rewriting your code to conform to wero's answer/ suggestion, using `getCanonicalFile()`, as it is a more elegant choice.  I'm currently the single up-vote on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `File.getCanonicalFile()` to norm the resulting string. It converts to the right separator and also removes `.` path segments.

```
String s = "E:\\git\\project\\codeAdapters\\rampAdapter\\./ramp_adapter/user_1001/ramp_file_receipt/3";
File f = new File(s).getCanonicalFile();
assertEquals("E:\\git\\project\\codeAdapters\\rampAdapter\\ramp_adapter\\user_1001\\ramp_file_receipt\\3", f.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory `.` depends on how i.e. where the application was started. You might use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

instead of getting the absolute path.

It probably will exhibit the same problem: clicking under Windows will be problematic.

The solution/workaround might be to have a batch file under Windows.

I tend to use an application dependent directory in the user's home folder. When hidden with a preceding period:

```
File myAppDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.myappname";
myAppDir.mkdir();
```

Comment: `File` has constructors that append paths so you don't have to do string concatenation. Because that's a bad thing to do.

Comment: @zapl good remark; I wanted to call `mkdir(s)` first. Maybe nowadays I should have used `Path, Paths.get(...), Files`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use System.getProperty("file.separator") to obtain the current OS file 
separator.
2) new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()  will return linux paths (/etc/uus/.)in Linux and Windows paths in windows (ex: C:\xpto\sdfs.)

You need to standardize as you wish.